# How can I build and install a C program on OS X with debugging symbols?

Tags: c, macos, debug-symbols

How can I build and install a C program with debugging symbols on OS X?

I'm trying to build something ([mutt](http://www.mutt.org/)) with debugging symbols on OS X, to help me track down a crash. I'm basically following the Homebrew formula for mutt in my build process. But no matter what I try, the resulting binary has no debugging symbols. I build it with `CFLAGS='-g -O0'` (after having also tried the default `'-g -O2'` in the Makefile). I can see when I see the make output go by that it is using these flags as it should be, and I don't see any `strip` or `install -s` invocations; but the resulting binary has no debugging symbols, as seen by trying to run it in gdb or lldb, or running dsymutil on it.

I'm trying to understand [the Valgrind instructions](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.erropts) on the matter; basically, they say that the linker on OS X doesn't actually put debug symbols that exist in the object files into the linked result -- I read that as saying you have to run dsymutil on the linked result, but I'm a little unsure as to whether that automatically pulls in the symbols from the object files, or if there's some way I need to specify them.

And even if I knew exactly how to use dsymutil here, I don't see that there are any debug symbols in any of the .o files.

Finally, I'm wondering if a "proper" installation, once I got the debugging symbols into the binary, would copy that .dSYM directory into /usr/local/bin along with mutt; or if it would go somewhere else. I know in Debian-based systems you can install specifically debuggable versions of libraries using the package manager, but I don't know if it's a best practice (or even a practice that's common) to actually install things with debug symbols in OS X. If nothing else, I can probably just run the debuggable binary from its build directory, so this doesn't seem like a big deal.

I've tried building with gcc and clang, with the same disappointing results.

Comment: Compile and link with the `-g` option.  The debugging information ends up in `program.dSYM` directory — automatically when you link a program from a single object file, or when you run `dsymutil program`.

Comment: The Makefile is already building everything (including the final binary) with `-g -O0`.

Comment: Good. That's necessary but not sufficient.